# Cannot find where to put directory path

Tags: php

```
function makeDirFromDate($path)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s.u');


    if (!mkdir($path . '/' . $date, 0, TRUE))

        return FALSE;

    return TRUE
}
```

am having troubles making this script run every time I refresh my browser to create another folder that adds a variable. So if I go to domain.com/script/testfolder/create_dir.php and run this file in the folder called create_dir.php it will create another folder within testfolder with the current year month day hour mintue second and microsecond and so on. The problem is I am having troubles on deciphering where I need to put the domain.com/script/testfolder/ to tell it to create the folders in there.

So the exact dirctory path should be domain.com/script/testfolders/ but no matter where i put it (i've tried the two below) neither work

```
makeDirFromDate('/domain.com/script/testfolders/');
mkdir("/domain.com/script/testfolders/$date")
```

I have put both of these replacing the top function and i have also put it under the $date by defining $path = but neither seem to work. what am i doing wrong? where do i put /domain.com/script/testfolders/

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: is this Linux? windows? which OS does your server run

Comment: This is Linux, its just not creating the folders at all in any directory. I have access to do so and the script has access to the folder.

Comment: from the root of the system, does the directory "/domain.com/script/testfolders" exist with permissions to write? Are you running the script under apache or your user? or are you trying for relative path?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to call **domain.com/script/testfolder/create_dir.php** and want to create new folder in the same place, right?

Try this one, but handle with caution:

```
makeDirFromDate(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Use .htaccess or other solution to deny access to create_dir.php for anyone else but you.